# warning: the home dir /var/lib/dradis you specified already exists

Tags: apt, dpkg

i have issues with network manager and cant access it...its say network manager is not compatible with this version..

i tried to reinstall and the install it gives the following error

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install network-manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gdebi-core imagemagick-common libegl1-mesa-drivers libpython3.4-minimal
  libpython3.4-stdlib python3.4 python3.4-minimal
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 493 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,368 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 338228 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../network-manager_1.4.2-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking network-manager (1.4.2-3) over (1.4.2-3) ...
Setting up dradis (3.1.0~rc2+git20160609-0kali2) ...
Warning: The home dir /var/lib/dradis you specified already exists.
The system user `dradis' already exists. Exiting.
Could not find rake-11.2.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
dpkg: error processing package dradis (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 7
Setting up network-manager (1.4.2-3) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-2) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.14-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dradis
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

please help is required in this issue...and i am a beginner to linux

Comment: *is not compatible with* what ? Please give more details.

Comment: The error message that caused the install to fall is `Could not find rake-11.2.2 in any of the sources`. How did you install `bundler`? Search for this error message, there are some answers on StackOverflow and Unix.SE.

Comment: i jsut installed update and upgrade it

Comment: but when i try to install bundle it say you must not do it as root user

Comment: If it says so then please don't its helping you prevent potentially __harmful__ code running on your system.